# Why am I getting ImportError: No module named pip ' right after installing pip?

Tags: python, windows-7, pip

I have installed pip and ez setup. I also checked the system path and I can see the module in the folder structure. Still when I try to run the *pip* command, I get an Import error saying no module named pip. I am running 32-bit Python on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Just use the python installer and pip will be downloaded with it.

Answer (score 391, accepted):

Just be sure that you have included the Python executable in the Windows Environment Variables, System PATH variable, and then run:
`python -m ensurepip`.

or if you have permission issue, run:
`python -m ensurepip --user`

Comment: Error: `python.exe: No module named ensurepip`. I'm using the latest 3.7.1.

Comment: @Subin_Learner I had to use the installer - the ZIP version of Python simply doesn't work with PIP afaict

Comment: @PeterX Yes you are right. i used the installer, it worked.

Comment: don't forget to add C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts to the PATH variable so you can use pip after

Comment: @PeterX And what if one cannot use the installer?

Comment: Your command says pip requirement is satisfied but when running pip, it still get error:  `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip
While I reinforced reinstallation of pip in C:\Python39 :o :angry:

Comment: No need to add Path, the answer of "user2226755" below is the correct one. Tried and tested.

Comment: @PeterX using `py -m ensurepip`

Answer (score 114):

After running `get_pip.py` with Python embed, you have to modify your `pythonXX._pth` file in the root folder. Add `Lib\site-packages`, to get something like this:

```
pythonXX.zip
.
Lib\site-packages
# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site
```

If you don't, you will get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

or

> python-3.8.2-embed-amd64\python.exe: No module named pip

```
λ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
  File "python-3.8.2-embed-amd64\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

λ python -m pip
python-3.8.2-embed-amd64\python.exe: No module named pip
```

Comment: Thank you!
This helps for my Windows 10 embedded python 3.8 installation!

Comment: Becareful if you use virtualenv with embedded python, the environnement is not the same as normal installation some installation (with pip) can crash with error of type `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '*******'`.

Comment: This should undoubtedly be one of the top answers. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Urax this answer came 3 years after 

Comment: in my case uncomment `#import site` too

Comment: this was the solution. Something is wrong with python people

Answer (score 66):

This issue occurs with me while I was trying to upgrade pip version.
It was resolved with the following commands:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

The above command restores the pip and below mentioned upgrades it.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: worked like charm, thanks!

Comment: Worked with me as well. Thanks

Answer (score 34):

What solved the issue on my case was go to:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts
```

And run below command:

```
easy_install.exe pip
```

Comment: Worked for me valid in 2019. Thanks a ton

Comment: Worked for me, too.

Comment: I get same error: "Fatal error in launcher..."

Answer (score 27):

Follow steps given in https://michlstechblog.info/blog/python-install-python-with-pip-on-windows-by-the-embeddable-zip-file/. Replace `x` with version number of Python.

1. Open the `pythonxx.__pth` file, located in your python folder.
2. Edit the contents (e.g. `D:\Pythonx.x.x` to the following):

```
 D:\Pythonx.x.x 
 D:\Pythonx.x.x\DLLs
 D:\Pythonx.x.x\lib
 D:\Pythonx.x.x\lib\plat-win 
 D:\Pythonx.x.x\lib\site-packages
```

Comment: This works; in my installation the directory was Lib, not lib.

Comment: Another issue was https://bugs.python.org/issue34841. The current directory was not added to the path. print(sys.path) did not include the empty string.

Answer (score 11):

It turned out I had two versions of the Python executable on my laptop.

Both commands worked for me

```
python -m ensurepip
py -m ensurepip
```

Both with another installation path

```
c:\tools\python\lib\site-packages
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages
```

Only the first path was in my %PATH% variable.

Answer (score 10):

Try to type *pip3* instead of *pip*.

Also for upgrading pip, don’t use pip3 in the command

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 9):

First make sure that `python` is added in environment variable.

Try checking the version of `pip` or `pip3`. Use these commands to check.

For `pip`:

```
pip --version
```

For `pip3`:

```
pip3 --version
```

If you can see any version of pip and still not able to use it, then run the following command.

```
python -m ensurepip
```

This ensures the `pip` in your system.

Answer (score 8):

I found this post while looking for a solution for the same problem. I was using an embedded Python distribution. In this case, the solution is to uncomment `import site` in the file `python<version>._pth`.

Answer (score 6):

Running these 2 commands helped me:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

`python get-pip.py`

Answer (score 6):

If you wrote

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and you got

```
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.2.1
    Uninstalling pip-20.2.1:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError...
```

Then you have uninstalled pip instead install pip. This could be the reason of your problem.

The [Gorodeckij Dimitrij's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip/42531427#42531427) works for me.

```
python -m ensurepip
```

Answer (score 5):

The `ensurepip` module was added in version 3.4 and then backported to 2.7.9.

So make sure your Python version is at least 2.7.9 if using Python 2, and at least 3.4 if using Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

I'v solved this error by setting the correct path variables

```
    C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts
    C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue and resolved it using the following steps.

1. Go to your Python package and rename "python37._pth" to python37._pth.save
2. `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
3. then run `python get-pip.py`
4. `pip install django`

Comment: Who said anything about [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)? Why is that relevant?

Answer (score 2):

The method I'm going to tell might not be the correct way to do it. But this method solved my issue. I tried every solution on YouTube and Stack Overflow methods.

1. If you have two Python versions installed. Delete one. I have the Python 3.8.1 and 3.9.0 versions installed. I deleted version 3.9.0 from the C directory.
2. Now go to the control panel → *System and security* → *System* → *Advanced system settings*.

   [image]

   Click on 'Environment Variables'.

   [image]

   Select the path and click on 'Edit...'

   Now, add the path of the Python executable and also the path of pip module. In my case it was *C:\python38* and *C:\python38\scripts*.

This method solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this error downloading the executable file for python 3.7.
I've had downloaded the embeddeable version and got that error.
Now it works! :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Python zip install python by python installer. It fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Usally upgrading the pipline will solve the problem, when upgrading check that you have the permission (in case you are working from Command Line)

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score -1):

Here i need to do this things:

1 - Redownload python 3.9 (https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/python-3.9.0.exe)

2 - Reinstall

3 - Edit the file python3.9._pth

```
C:\Laragon\bin\python\python-3.9.0 
C:\Laragon\bin\python\python-3.9.0\DLLs 
C:\Laragon\bin\python\python-3.9.0\Lib 
C:\Laragon\bin\python\python-3.9.0\Lib\plat-win  
C:\Laragon\bin\python\python-3.9.0\Lib\site-packages

# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site
```

4 - run the command  "python -m pip install requests"