# python virtualenv on windows: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, anaconda

I have created a virtualenv in python 2.7 (Anaconda) on a dev machine and (after package installation) copied it to another windows machine in a PROD setting (no communication to outside). Executing any of the installed ".exe" entry points for a program in the virtualenv produces this error on the target machine however runs fine on the source machine:

```
(env) D:\app\pyvenv>env\Scripts\pip.exe
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

The location of python installation on both machines is set to the same folder:  `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2`

Also see my additional notes at the bottom of this post. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using)

Comment: My question is not the same however very close.

1. My version of python is 2.7 and not 3
2. I'm running this in a virtualenv
3. Upgrading or installing anything on the destination is NOT possible since there is no connectivity anywhere. Had there been connectivity to the outside world I would not have run into this problem to begin with.
4. All other suggestions just don't apply

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I previously changed the name of the python.exe executable to python3.exe so when I run:

```
virtualenv project1_env
```

it can't locate the python.exe if that was your case too .. just rename it again to python.exe and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solve by upgrading pip using following code in activate environment.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Run this while in the venv. seems like a system change occured and reinstalling it restores it to default.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I uninstalled venv and then installed it again and it worked.
`pip uninstall virtualenv` to uninstall it and use `pip install virtualenv` to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try making virtualenv with this command:

```
virtualenv --python C:\Path\To\Python\python.exe venv
```

Note that you should specify the path to your python installation folder after `--python` option.