# What does "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using" mean?

Tags: python, module, directory, pip, command-prompt

None of the current error inquiries addressed my specific situation (it seems like a pretty well rounded problem). I am trying to install Pillow (image module for Python). I have the correct version of the whl file, and the correct installation of Python 3.6. My paths have been confirmed. 
Steps that I took:

1. Downloaded the whl file
2. Opened downloads in command window
3. Typed the pip path, install, and then my whl file.

Then I got the error: "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using"

Comment: and then you got the error ? should we predict what the error is ?

Comment: Presumably he means the error in the title.

Comment: edited for further clarification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using)

Answer (score 4):

use 'python -m puse 'python -m pip install package-name' instead.