# Trying to install easy_install or pip for django

Tags: python, django, pip, easy-install

I am trying to install Django and here is what I get when I try to install pip => " Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"' When I enter de command => python -m pip install XXX   it does not work. Any help?

Comment: *does not work* is hardly a question. What command did you try and wht was the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pip install yourpackagename
```

good luck

Comment: Nope. Same error message: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"' But thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Download PyCharm and in the terminal it will be easier.   set interpretator then **pip install** in terminal.