# Can't lauch tensorboard -- unable to create processing using ''''

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-7-x64

I have Windows 7 and the latest tensorflow (version 1.3), and Python 3 installed.

The command I'm running is from cmd:

```
tensorboard --logdir=c:\tmp\retrain_logs
```

My installations (tensorflow)

```
pip3.6 list:

tensorflow (1.3.0)
tensorflow-gpu (1.2.0rc2)
tensorflow-tensorboard (0.1.8)
```

The error message I'm getting is:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: try: python -m tensorflow.tensorboard --logdir...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using)

Comment: @ivan7707 that seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python -m tensorflow.tensorboard --logdir...
```