# python library not installing

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am using python 3.6. I am trying to install a new library using (on windows) but I get the error : Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'.
I am in the directory where pip library is present. Please help!

Comment: change to your home directory and try again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using)

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:-**

```
import pip
pip.main(["install","your module"])
```

Comment: Using `pip.main()` is deprecated and will be remved in the future. Also I'm sure it doesn't help the OP.