# installing jupiter notebook is not working: fatal error in launcher

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

os: Windows 10
python: 3.6

when I try to install JN, using this command:

```
pip install notebook
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

the only solution I found online:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

is not helping, I get:

```
Requirement already up-to-date:
```

another thing I found is:

```
Copy & Paste the standalone python into the ampps/python folder and overwriting the python version provided by AMPPS
```

but I have no idea what does this means - what is AMPPS,  where can find its folder, where can I find the standalone python, what is the standalone python.

how can I solve this?

Comment: How did you find the last bit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using

Comment: How did you install python (which version), what OS are you on and what is the full error you get along the `Fatal error in launcher` one?

Comment: Forget about the `Copy & Paste the standalone python into the ampps...` bit. AMPPS is a Software that ships with an in-built python, so it is not applicalbe in this case

Comment: updates question with os and python versions. this is the full error.