# i stuck with these error in django there all command work but if i want start server these error occur

Tags: python, django, networking, terminal

Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Bunty Waghmare\Desktop\env_site\Scripts\python.exe manage.py runserver[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfw9W.jpg)

Comment: Please add code and error messages as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

there must be something wrong with the virtual environment you have made, like a directory is missing or things like that, please [try these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using). i'm trying to give you a better clue by saying its not about your django project. its about your virtual environment or even your OS