# how do I pip install on the command prompt? "fatal error in launcher"

Tags: python, cmd, pip, fatal-error, launcher

**C:\Users\Utente>pip install
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Utente\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install'**

Why do I get a Fatal error in launcher while installing pip on command prompt?

Kindly help me  with this error "c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe"

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to install python and pip comes with it (in the bin folder). The `pip install` expects the name of the python library after that. For example `pip install pandas`. This is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help ,I tried it but it gave me this:      C:\Users\Utente>pip install pandas
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Utente\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install pandas'

Comment: Based on what I see here the pip.exe and python.exe have different path. Can you try using the pip from the same folder?  i.e. c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\pip install pandas. OR do ls c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python38 to see if pip exist here.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your help. It worked .It turns out the "c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe"    was a wrong path set inside the   environmental variables