# Git review is not installing using PIP

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, git-review

**C:\Users\Dell>pip install git-review**

**Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install git-review': The system cannot find the file specified**

I am getting this error i have tried many way to resolve it.
by installing pip and python again.
and trying old question to solve this error but unable to solve

Comment: Can you install other packages using pip?

Comment: not tried yet..suggest me some to install

Comment: eg. ``python -m pip install numpy``

Comment: Try this ``python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`` and then ``python -m pip install git-review``

Comment: Thanks @programandoconro ..........its really worked by adding python -m before pip worked for me......can u plz give me brief why normally written pip install git-review is not working..

Comment: I updated my answer explaining why it is better to use ``python -m pip`` than just ``pip``. Please mark it as solved if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`

Then install `git-review` using `python -m pip install git-review`.

Using `python -m pip install` instead of just `pip install` is recommended. The reason is that it will use the correct interpreter for your python installation, specially if you have many versions installed. More details here: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Cheers!

Comment: Already tried,Sucessfully install pip but not able to install git-review

Answer (score 0):

Could be many things, you're very likely to find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using). (Posted as answer because I don't have enough rep yet for commenting)

Answer (score 0):

As @programandoconro mentioned in comment

python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip and then python -m pip install git-review

worked for me