# How to install the pygmentize module on Python 3.3.6

Tags: python, module, pip, windows-xp, pygmentize

I'm trying to install the pygmentize module on a Windows XP computer which uses `Python 3.3.6` (Sep 29th, 2012)

When I did `pip install pygmentize` it returned `windows XP Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process` so I've applied this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using) and here it is how went:

```sh
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/d7/f505e91e2cdea53cfcf51f4ac478a8cd64fb0629cedde20d9a6a9b/pip-21.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB)
    100% |################################| 1.6MB 87kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-7.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-7.1.2
Successfully installed pip-21.2.2
```

When I've tried to install again:

```sh
$ pip install pygmentize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programs\python-3.3\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\programs\python-3.3\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Programs\python-3.3\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\programs\python-3.3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named 'typing'
```

Assuming that `pip-21.2.2` is fully compatible with `pyrhon-3.3.6` I think it's caused by my `python-3.3.6` being incompatible with the current version of `pygmentize` If that is the case how can I check which version of `pygmentize` is compatible with `python-3.3.6` and how can I install that *compatible* version of it in `python-3.3.6` ?

Comment: [`pip` 21.2.2](https://pypi.org/project/pip/21.2.2/) is not compatible with Python 3.3, it requires Python 3.6+. For Python 3.3 you need `pip` 10.0.1 (anything < 18). Download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.3/get-pip.py and see how to use it to fix your `pip`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/7976758. Then upgrade with `pip install --upgrade "pip < 18"`

Answer (score 0):

If you use pycharm you can go to "python-packages" and search for pygmentize then install it