# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ... (Visual Studio)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

Ran into an issue today. I noticed that Visual Studio 2019 created a "Shared" version of my Python 3.7 to run within itself, however when I'm using Jupyter-Lab, I don't want to route through that Shared folder at all. So I deleted the Python folder in the Visual Studio folder path, and then used the Visual Studio Installer to uninstall Python from it's packages list, but now I'm getting this error whenever I try to run jupyter-lab from command prompt:

```
C:\Users\...\OneDrive\Desktop\Python_Scripts\QA_System>jupyter-lab
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe"  "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\jupyter-lab.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I checked my environment variables, the `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37` and `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts` are in both PATHs still, and there is no path to that visual studio shared folder at all, yet it seems like visual studio is still trying to use its own instance of python.exe to run, when it shouldn't, it should just be using the `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts` path. How can I get visual studio out of this equation without having to do a clean uninstall/re-install of either?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing the 3 steps involved on the main answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using) as `pip` was also giving me the same issue. Then, I ran `pip uninstall jupyterlab`, then `pip install jupyterlab`. I assume I'll have to do this with other packages as they come up, but this should fix it eventually.