# "py -m pip" works but "pip" returns "Fatal error in launcher"

Tags: python, windows, powershell, shell, pip

I just installed Python 3.10.1 on Windows 11 and while following some tutorials I started with the basics of making sure everything looks right in the command prompt. I also added all the necessary data into the PATH variable.

When I run the simple command `pip`, the result is "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified."

However, when I run the command `py -m pip` I get the results I would expect when running `pip`.

Is there a way to fix the original command, or is this a new Windows 11 or Python 3.10.1 update of syntax?

Comment: Why did you tag `PowerShell`?

Comment: Because I'm doing this in PowerShell. I apologize if I did this wrong, I'm just learning my way around posting in StackOverflow

Comment: Can you try the steps suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228413/6698642) ? Step 3 seems to have worked for a lot of people with broken `pip` but working `python -m pip`.