# Poetry install throws WinError 1312 when running over SSH on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, ssh, operating-system, python-poetry

I have an SSH connection from a Windows machine to another, and then trying to do a poetry install.

**My problem is**:
I get this error when executing poetry install **through ssh**:

```
[WinError 1312] A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

This command works perfectly when I execute it locally on the target machine, but fails when connecting through ssh.

**How can I get rid/fix the [WinError 1312]?**

I saw another user that posted the same question recently, but removed it.

I've seen some clues regarding the MachineKeys, but have really no idea on how to proceed. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

---

Python: 3.10.8

Poetry: 1.2.1

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing install-requires (0.3.0)

  OSError

  [WinError 1312] A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py:53 in check_zero
       49│
       50│ def check_zero_factory(function_name=None):
       51│     def check_zero(result, function, arguments, *args):
       52│         if result == 0:
    →  53│             raise make_error(function, function_name)
       54│         return result
       55│     return check_zero
       56│
       57│

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  error

  (1312, 'CredRead', 'A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.')

  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py:37 in pywin32error
       33│ def pywin32error():
       34│     try:
       35│         yield
       36│     except WindowsError as exception:
    →  37│         raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
       38│
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Clarified, thanks for the heads up @ellhe-blaster.

Comment: i have the same issue on Windows Home. Works correctly on a local session, but fails with 1312 over ssh for both Command and Powershell ssh sessions.

Have tried the disable option in "Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication" with gpedit.msc without success.

Comment: Are you sure this is the full stack trace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on similarities in the stack traces and your description, my guess is that you're facing the same bug from [#1892](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/1892) and [#1917](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1917), where Poetry tries to use your keyring to access/publish modules, and hence fails when these credentials are invalid.

> But it appears that poetry tries to access the keyring even for install operations.

One of the solutions proposed was to uninstall the `keyring` package remotely:

> For me, I worked around the problem by pip uninstalling the 'keyring' package from that virt env.

Another solution is to export the environment variable `PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND`. Here's an example of how you can do that on Windows cmd:

```
SET PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring
```

or Windows powershell:

```
$env:PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND="keyring.backends.null.Keyring"
```

or Linux shell:

```
export PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring
```

Unfortunately, it appears that issue #1917 is still open and unresolved, so this is the best workaround that you can find to fix the issue for now.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this without success. Error morphs into:

`Command C:\...\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --disable-pip-version-check --isolated --no-
input --prefix C:\...\.venv --no-deps C:\...\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts\c4\3d\37
\...\ipython-8.7.0-py3-none-any.whl errored with the following return code 101, and
 output:
  Unable to create process using...
`

Comment: It sounds like your Python venv installation has problems with the PATH (env variables), check [these answers out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37220055/11985743), maybe they will help :)

Comment: Update: the above error appeared to be transient, and with a clean restart+retry  it all worked smoothly. Fixed for me!

Comment: It worked for me too, thanks a lot for the workaround!!