# Installing a new package for python does not work

Tags: python

I am trying to install a new Python package by using this command:
`pip install <package name>`

And I get this error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe"
```

The problem is that my computer is trying to reach the wrong folder.
How can I change the folder pip is trying to reach?

Comment: pip is not trying to reach any folder because your operating system is not able to start pip.

Comment: Just re-run the command with `python -m pip install <package name>`.  You can also be very specific with `<path-to-python-executable> -m pip install <package name>`.

Comment: See also: [Pip - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `Python` path in System environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the command prompt:

```
py -m pip install <package name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Unable to create process ..." during a `pip install` operation in Python usually means that there's an issue with either the Python installation or the environment configs. Personally I recommend trying step [4] and using a Python virtual environment, but here's some other possible fixes to look at:

1. **Check Python Installation:**

- I assume you've probably done this, but just for safe measure, check your Python installation by navigating to the `C:\Python39` directory and checking if `python.exe` is present.

2. **[Python Environment Variables PATHs](https://blog.enterprisedna.co/python-set-environment-variable/):**

   - Make sure that Python is correctly added to the PATH env vars. This is what allows your operating system to locate the Python executable.
   - You can check this by typing `python` in the command prompt; if Python runs, it's in the PATH.
3. **Specify --target path for package installation:**

   - Instead of just typing `pip install <package-name>`, try using the `--target` flag to specify a directory to install your Python packages. You can do this by running

```
pip install <package-name> --target="C:\path\to\folder"
```

in your terminal.

4. **Better Yet: Use a [Virtual Environment:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)**

   - Using a virtual environment is **great** for avoiding these type of issues, as it doesn't change the pip folder globally but it allows you to maintain separate environments with different packages and versions. You create a virtual environment in a specific directory, and pip will install packages in that environment.

- In case you might have already accidentally set up a virtual environment, juat go to your project folder, delete the current environment first before  rebuilding it:
- Navigate to the project folder, and delete the current env:

```
cd <project-folder> 
pipenv --rm
```

- Rebuild the Python virtual environment:

```
 pipenv install
```

If you're using VSCode, you can also [set up your virtual env](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) through the command palette (Shift+CMD+P on Mac, Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows), and type "Python: Create Environment". If you're creating a virtual env with Venv, the command gives you a list of Python versions to run your environment (you can also change this using "Python: Select Interpreter" in the command palette).