# I think iam getting something wrong

Tags: django, anaconda, django-admin, miniconda

recently i tried to setup my environment using miniconda so,
i download python and django in my environment so, when is started my django project

`django-admin startproject myproject`

i got this error:

`Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Yoga 260.conda\envs\myenv\python.exe “C:\Users\Yoga 260.conda\envs\myenv\Scripts\django-admin-script.py”`

how i could solve the issue

i tried to delete env and create new one but it didn't work also i started from scratch and deleted everything

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using. Please check.