# How to use "python -m pip install [package] in windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7-x64

I've set the environment variable "Path" and included `D:\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;D:\Python\Python36-32\;` in it.

This is the program installation process with a picture.

[image: This is the program installation process with a picture.]

It's a wrong message.

[image: It's a wrong message.]

Who can tell me why I got this mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting ImportError: No module named pip ' right after installing pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip)

Comment: Have you tried simply 'python -m pip install scrapy' rather than python.exe?

Comment: works perfect on my 64-bit windows 3.6. yes, there's a "scripts" subdir from where you can get `pip.exe`

Comment: I've use "py -m pip install [package] and python -m pip install [package] to excuted".

The error was same.

Answer (score 2):

The another way is to add pip to environment variables in windows.
You may refer [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)  to add the same. And then run pip install scrapy.
Syntax:

pip install "package".

Comment: I've included this path in installing.

Comment: try "pip -V" which ensures that you have installed pip path correctly.
Then you may try pip install scrapy.

Answer (score 1):

`pip.exe` file is in the `Scripts` folder, inside Python root. Try: `cd Scripts`, `pip.exe install package`

Comment: I didn't find "pip.exe" in Scripts folder. The official said:"It had included in python.exe binary."