# pip - No module named 'pip' even after successful installation

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I am trying to install pip on my Windows 10 system. I got the get-pip.py file and ran the command

```
python get-pip.py
```

Here's a snapshot of the terminal

```
$ python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/dc/7fd5df840e
fb3e56c8b4f768793a237ec4ee59891959d6a215d63f727023/pip-19.0.1-py2
.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/47/1dfa4795e
24fd6f93d5d58602dd716c3f101cfd5a77cd9acbe519b44a0a9/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3- 
none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed pip-19.0.1 setuptools-40.8.0 wheel-0.32.3
```

Now when I try to check the version with

```
pip -V
```

I get this -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
 File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
 File "C:\Program Files\Python\python-3.6.3-embed- 
 amd64\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Why is this happening? It JUST said pip installed successfully and when I try to see the version to check if its installed, it says `No module named 'pip'`

Also, I have included C:/Program/Files/Python/python3/Scripts in the PATH variable.

Please help ! ! ! !

Comment: Have you tried to restart your laptop? Or tried any solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1) ?

Comment: Tried to restart the system and checked with pip -V. Still getting the same "No module named 'pip' " error. :(

Comment: try `pip3 -V` also not working?

Comment: @gameon67, same error. :'( no module named 'pip'

Comment: python 3 comes with pip so you shouldn't have needed to install it. Also, are you sure you installed python for all users? if not its likely your python 3 is installed at the directory c:/users/<your user>/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/

Comment: @typedefstructJames, if pip is already installed how come it says "command not found" if I try to do "pip -V" ??

Comment: you would still need to add the correct environment path variable, which is why I asked are you sure its not located in the directory I just named?

Comment: try `python -m ensurepip` ?

Comment: @typedefstructJames, I just checked C:/users/<your user>/appdata/local/programs/python/python37/ and python is installed there. So what? I have added python PATH to my environment variables and it is available everywhere to use.

Comment: or add `C:\Python34\Scripts` to your PATH

Comment: @gameon67, I have already added Scripts to my PATH. Mentioned that in my question.

Comment: so if it is located in appdata/local/ ... the appropriate path to add would NOT be `C:/Program/Files/Python/python3/Scripts`, it would be `c:/users/<your user>/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/scripts/`. If this STILL doesnt work for you I would suggest re-installing python and make sure you click `add PATH variable` while installing so the install process will handle this for you

Comment: @typedefstructJames, my issue here is with pip installation. Python is running fine. I tried to install pip again with the new PATH variable - still doesn't work. :'(

Comment: I understand your issue... pip is located in `c:/users/<your user>/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/scripts/`. If this path is not added to your environment variables then you will not be able to launch it from the command line. Again, pip comes packaged with python3 so there is no need to install over it. Re-installing python and clicking `add python to path` would solve this for you. Additionally, once you modify your environment variables you must close your terminal and open a new one for the changes to take place.

Comment: navigate to `c:/users/<your user>/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/scripts/`, if pip.exe is in there, you have pip.

Comment: @typedefstructJames, do I navigate to this folder and check pip -V? When I try it, I STILL get the no module error. :(

Comment: @KrithikaRaghavendran just a suggestion. on windows 10, you could install Ubuntu as an app from app store and then you could do most of your work inside that. Its sort of like a virtual environment and saves you a lot of development time

Answer (score 19):

After running python get-pip.py, python install-dir will increase dir Lib\site-packages

Method 1. try to cp the pip dir into the python install-dir

or

Method 2. change file python3x._pth in python install-dir，append this line Lib\site-packages

run pip, problem will be solved

Comment: cheers @demianzhang not sure why the answer isn't accepted. But Method 1 worked for me.

Comment: You could also make a symlink named pip in your Python installation directory.
`mklink /D pip .\Lib\site-packages\pip`

Answer (score 9):

- Open **python37._pth** file which is in the root folder of python.
- Add `Lib\site-packages` line.

All will work fine.

Comment: Thank you. Of all the advice offered for this problem, this is the one thing that actually worked. :)

Answer (score 5):

The following steps may be followed to install pip on windows:

1. Download python file: get-pip.py (nearly 1.8 MB size) from link: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py and save it to your desktop
2. Go to command prompt and Check your python version: c:> python
3. From command prompt run: c:> python  get-pip.py
4. The above will install new version of pip. check by running C:> pip --version
5. You may also update setup tools - C:> pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

Answer (score 5):

I suggest referring to the pip homepage: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/
It describes all methods on how to install pip.
I am a win10 user so the solution was to run this command:

```
py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Comment: Could you update your answer to include syntax highlighting? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: "No module named ensurepip"

Comment: I can attest this solution worked when hitting this error on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

```
py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

this is work for me official docs link you can try multiple methods based on os.
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Answer (score 0):

Use following commands can be used to find out whether pip extraction path is included or not.

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

if `Lib\site-packages` path is not included then update file `python37._pth`.

Run the command again and path should be visible.

`pip install <module name>` worked successfully for me after this.

Thanks [@demianzhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7990199/demianzhang) for the hint or even for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found files in my Windows lib\site-packages directory
~ip
~ip-20-0.2.dist-info

Renamed them to 
pip
pip-20-0.2.dist-info

And it worked to run pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 0):

> If your Python environment does not have pip installed, there are 2
> mechanisms to install pip supported directly by pip’s maintainers:
>
> 1. ensurepip
> 2. get-pip.py

**Method 1**

> **ensurepip**
> Python comes with an ensurepip module1, which can install
> pip in a Python environment.

1. Linux: `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`
2. MacOc: `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`
3. Windows: `py -m ensurepip --upgrade`

**Method 2**

> **get-pip.py** This is a Python script that uses some bootstrapping logic
> to install **pip**.
>
> Download the script, from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py.
>
> Open a terminal/command prompt, cd to the folder containing the
> get-pip.py file and run:

1. Linux: `python get-pip.py`
2. MacOc: `python get-pip.py`
3. Windows: `py get-pip.py`

Above installation commands are in official `python` [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/).

**Optional**

After successful installation of `pip` you might want to **upgrade** `pip` to latest version

for Linux and MacOs `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

for Windows :  `py -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by opening my shell as admin

Comment: Had the same message erros and it worked, no need to downvote, otherwise post your answer instead or downvote all the answers that didn't work for you