# Setting up Pip on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

I have explored many other questions about the installation of [pip on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585852/pip-no-module-named-pip-even-after-successful-installation). However, I have had no luck.

I have seen for Python 3.4+ that pip comes with it. I can see pip in the site-packages folder, but trying to run `pip -V` I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

I successfully added python to the PATH. I then downloaded the [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) file and ran. I made cure to add C:.../Scripts to PATH. Again I tried `pip -V` and had the same issue.

Also tried `python -m pip -V` as suggested in the comments and got this error:

```
C:\Users\apowell\Documents\python-3.7.4-embed-amd64\python.exe: No module named pip
```

I'm a little lost now on how to successfully use pip. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
For further details, I am doing this all on a virtual machine. I have python/pip all set up on my local machine. What would be the process for copying from my local machine to the VM?

Comment: Maybe try some of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip) answers, helped me too when I was having problems with python and pip on windows

Comment: Does `python -m pip -V` give you an error? If so, can you post the full error in your question body?

Comment: @KevinMüller I attempted this, but got `C:\Users\....\python.exe: No module named ensurepip`

Comment: There are some different answers you should also try, not just the accepted one. Otherwise just uninstall and install python again, and make sure to tick the box at the bottom to install it for all users.

Comment: @DavidZemens added to the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the [embeddable package](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-embeddable-package). It is not meant to be used as is. You should probably try installing Python with the [full installer](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#windows-full) instead. Here is the [full installer for Python 3.7.4 Windows 64 bits](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/python-3.7.4-amd64.exe).

Comment: Anyway to do without the installer??

Comment: Probably. Find the `._pth` file and uncomment the `import site` line. Maybe it will then find the pip you installed with `get-pip.py`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48906746/11138259