# windows 10 python shell command to install returning an error

Tags: python

I am trying to install a list of packages from a text file by running a batch file.

```
install_python_modules.bat has:

    python -m pip install -r python_modules_requirements.txt
    @REM python -m pip install slimit
    @REM python -m pip install pycparser

etc. etc.
```

I am receiving "`No module named pip`" .
What is my machine missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting ImportError: No module named pip ' right after installing pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip)

Comment: other than notifying this untrue comment, can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a PATH problem. The first test would be opening a command prompt and simply typing 'python' - if there is an output other than the following:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

then the problem is not PATH.

If you can launch python but not pip, then it's most likely a directory error. Try navigating to
C:/Program Files/Python
or
C:/Program Files(x86)/Python
or, as [tgikal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4777984/tgikal) mentioned,
C:/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Programs
and opening the 'Scripts' folder. There, you should find the pip.exe executable, and if you start a command prompt in that folder, it should work.

On the topic of resolving the issue permanently, check out [this](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) guide to add pip.exe to your path.

Comment: It seems like python is more commonly installed to `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python` now days.