# Pip error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install a python library with pip I got this error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I heve also tryed to run
`py -3.9 -m pip install <library-name>`
but I got a similar error:

```sh
C:\Python39\python.exe: No module named pip
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install <module-name>`?

Comment: Have you installed pip? Try `pip -v` to check if you have installed pip.

Comment: Yes, I have tried both and I got the same error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`

Comment: Is this answering your question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip)?

Comment: Running `python -m ensurepip` I got `Requirement already satisfied`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting ImportError: No module named pip ' right after installing pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you have added Python to Windows Environment Variable called PATH.

Then run  `python -m ensurepip`

**Alternative Solution**:

Navigate to Python Scripts directory: (*Example*)

`cd C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts`

and run `easy_install.exe pip`

Comment: "python - m ensurepip" -> "no module named ensurepip". "easy_install.exe pip" -> "...easy_install.exe not a recognized command...