# Pip is not working Within virtual environment (venv)

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I install python and set its path too. When I check in CMD pip, It shows me the following...

```
C:\Users\maher>pip --version
pip 21.1.2""
```

But after activation of virtual environment when I want to install any packeg using pip, thew see following error.

```
(data) PS D:\Masters_FIT\4th\Webdatabese\Project\Code\Data_Collection> pip install tablib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\maher\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\maher\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Masters_FIT\4th\Webdatabese\Project\Code\data\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>      
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
(data) PS D:\Masters_FIT\4th\Webdatabese\Project\Code\Data_Collection>
```

[My Project and environment director.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zec6n.jpg)

"data" is my environment name
"Data_Collection" is the Project name.

any help or suggestion will be welcome and thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you tried re-installing pip or upgrading pip in your virtual environment ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting ImportError: No module named pip ' right after installing pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip)

Comment: How did you create the virtualenv? Please include the python version (and - in case you are not using the python builtin venv module - the version of whatever you have created the virtualenv with). How are you activating the virtualenv? Did it ever work for you? (It seems you've created it at the beginning of May.)

Comment: Yes. I tried to upgrade pip but it says "Requirement already satisfied."  I'm using Python 3.7.3. First I install virtual environment package then I create. I active my venv by "data\Scripts\activate". Yes, I started this project in start of may.

Answer (score 5):

Please run:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

and if not resolve the issue run this:

```
c:\users\maher\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\scripts\easy_install.exe pip
```

Comment: python -m ensurepip => C:\Users\maher>python -m ensurepip
Looking in links: C:\Users\maher\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpk1dkvzfy
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\maher\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (57.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\maher\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (21.1.2)

Comment: for 2nd c:\Users\maher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32>easy_install.exe pip
'easy_install.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @AbdulRehman sorry for the second I forget to add the scripts folder  to the path, I fixed that

Answer (score 0):

May be by some reason pip and wheel did not install in your venv.
You may try `python -m pip install tablib` to check if pip is working as a module.

Comment: (data) PS D:\Masters_FIT\4th\Webdatabese\Project\Code\Data_Collection> python -m pip install tablib
D:\Masters_FIT\4th\Webdatabese\Project\Code\data\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip

Answer (score 0):

So I was having the same issue.
**How I got that issue is**

1. I have created venv and home in pyvenv.cfg is pointing to my
   anaconda dir. I wanted to change it(change the version of python
   from 3.8.8 to 3.11.0).
2. downloaded python 3.11.0 zip and pointed home in pyvenv.cfg to extract zip

Before editing home in pyvenv.cfg

[image: Before editing home in pyvenv.cfg]

After editing home in pyvenv.cfg

[image: After edit pyvenv.cfg]

**Here the problem started**

`python --version` is giving 3.11 but `pip --version` is throwing error

[image: Error when I try command pip]

**This is the fix I tried**

So, I have uncommented `import site` in `pythonxx._pth` (xx is python version downloaded)

before commenting:

[image: before editing python311._pth located in python-3.11.0-embed-amd64 extracted zip]

after removing the commit:

[image: afterediting python311._pth located in python-3.11.0-embed-amd64 extracted zip]

I also got this error when I python tried to use the cached wheel for installing packages

[image: Error after editing python311._pth]

then I tried to upgrade pip using cmd: `c:\users\sam\desktop\py\django\tst\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip` and `then pip install pands worked`

Note: when the python dir is changed (changing home var in pyvenv.cfg) uninstalling and re-installing packages will fix a few errors.