# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5]

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pycharm

i was trying to install tensorflow-gpu on my pycharm (`pip install tensorflow-gpu`), but unfortunately im getting a Error Message. How can i install this package on my pycharm? What is wrong here? Should i install it directly with cmd? How can I install them with pycharm? However, I was able to install the tenserflow Version 2.5.0 without any problems. Only the Tenserflow gpu I cannot install. Im using python Version 3.7.9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Could+not+install+packages+due+to+an+WinError+5+Access+denied

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to run the command prompt or terminal as an administrator. This will permit you to install packages.

And also, you need to upgrade pip to the latest version - `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` in cmd or terminal.

Comment: thx. Ive just startet my pycharm as an administrator and it works. I have succefully installed the packages abd also upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I opened Windows Terminal as an administrator and ran the above command and still got the same error message. Any thoughts?

Comment: I also was not able to install a package using cmd even with admin rights. However I tried to delete the file mentioned by pip and Windows reported the file was already open in Python. I realized I had Pycharm opened and closing the IDE allowed me to proceed with the install.

Comment: I had same issue and error when installing packages in Anaconda. Running Anaconda command prompt as an administrator solved the issue for me.

Comment: Getting [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\shraddha.shetty\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\~hinc\\backends\\cblas.cp39-win_amd64.pyd' while trying to install pip .can you tell me how to fix it - even upgraded pip still no use

Comment: it says C:\Python\python.exe: No module named pip

Comment: @YaroslavLukianenko https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip

Comment: python -m ensurepip --user -- still have problems with permissions or access..
so I decided to install windows components for linux and downloaded ubuntu from microsoft store and use python from there

Comment: @Logic1 This worked for me. I still had a script running in PyCharm in debug mode. Stopping this script resolved the permission issue.