# WinError 5 error, permissions needed to install tensorflow-gpu on jupyter with virtual environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I am having trouble installing tensorflow gpu in my computer that runs on windows 11 and has python 3.9.
The problem is that the error code indicates not having permissions to install [WinError 5]. When pasting this code into jupyter:

!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.6.1

The looks as follows:

*ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado: 'c:\users\medai\desktop\coding\tensorflow course\tfodcourse\tfod\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\experimental\microfrontend\python\ops\_audio_microfrontend_op.so'
Check the permissions.*

(Acceso denegado is Spanish for Denied Access)

Can someone help me with this issue please?
Have a nice day.

Comment: Found similar issue resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133846/error-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-winerror-5), which might help you to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the procedure outlined in https://windowsreport.com/access-is-denied-windows-10/. It worked for me. I have installed tensorflow-gpu successfully.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).