# Pip install upgrade denied

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, pycharm

Everytime I try to upgrade pip on VSC or Pycharm, I get:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip-19.2.3.dist-info\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Is there problem with accessing it bc administrator did not allow it?

Comment: Did you try using the `--user` option like it suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple 'cause here is a hint in the error *"Consider using the --user option or check the permissions."*

```py
pip install --upgrade <Module-Name> --user
```

You could take a look at my other answer with the same problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71859327/error-while-trying-to-install-pandas-through-pip-through-pycharm/71859417#71859417)

Answer (score 0):

The encountered issue involves upgrading the Python package manager, pip, using the command `py -m pip install --upgrade pip --user`. In some cases, this command may result in errors related to script locations. To address potential warnings, an alternative command is suggested: `py -m pip install --upgrade pip --user --no-warn-script-location`. This modified command includes the `--no-warn-script-location` option to suppress warnings associated with script locations during the upgrade process.

> First Command:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

`py:` This is a launcher for Python. It's used to run Python commands.
`-m pip:` This specifies that the pip module should be run.
`install:` It's the command to install packages.
`--upgrade pip:` This instructs pip to upgrade itself to the latest version.
`--user:` This flag installs the package just for the current user, avoiding the need for administrator privileges. It installs the package in the user-specific Python directory.

> Second Command:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

This command seems identical to the first one, but it's listed again in case there was a typo or error in the first attempt.
Added Option for Handling Errors:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip --user --no-warn-script-location
```

`--no-warn-script-location:` This option is added to suppress warnings related to the script location. When upgrading pip, sometimes there might be warnings about the location of scripts. This option helps to silence those warnings.
So, the first two commands are intended to upgrade pip for the user, and if there are any warnings related to the script location during the upgrade, the third command includes the --no-warn-script-location option to handle those warnings. This sequence of commands is useful in scenarios where a straightforward upgrade might not be successful due to specific environment configurations or permissions.