# Whenever I want to use pip I get a ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, modulenotfounderror

Whenever I type 'pip' into commandline I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I already tried to update 'pip' with using `c:\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip` but there I get:

```
c:\python39\python.exe: No module named pip
```

If I replace 'pip' with 'pip3' the same thing happens.

Here is a screenshot of the **path** variable in system environment variables which shows that pip and python are in the **path** variable.

[image]

---

Does anyone have ideas for me to fix this error so I can continue programming my python programs.

Comment: check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip

Comment: One thing you can do is go to all list of programs and edit python install from there

Answer (score -1):

you can try **pip3** instead of **pip**

Comment: With 'pip3' instead of 'pip' the same is happening