# Different versions in python and no modules named pip

Tags: python, pip, mingw, blender, msys

I put a lot of effort into this and things are even worst I am desperate as hell. Only what I wanted was to download with a pip module called PySimpleGUI and after, that things started to get worse and worse. I program plugins for blender and I wanted to execute another python file as a subprocess that needs PySimpleGUI for its running. So after the first not very successful attempt at solving the pip problem here([Why am I getting ImportError: No module named pip ' right after installing pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639074/why-am-i-getting-importerror-no-module-named-pip-right-after-installing-pip)), I decided to delete all the python files and versions on PC and start all over again with installing python. But even though I delete all the python files I still got a message in CMD about my version and that says my version is 3.9.10 although I installed 3.9.7. I removed all paths in env. variables and also all python folders from

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs

and I think I deleted some folders also here out of desperation

> C:\msys64\mingw64

Now if I try to write `pip --version` to CMD or `python3 -m ensurepip` (although I have installed python of version 3.9.7) this error occurs.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\bin\python.exe" -m pip install tkinter -t"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\lib\site-packages"
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\bin\python.exe: No module named pip

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python3 -m ensurepip
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\python3.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\python3.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.path = [
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python39.zip',
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python3.9',
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\lib-dynload',
    '',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000b4 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Only what is changing is current thread (Current thread 0x00004604, Current thread 0x00001dec,Current thread 0x00004e18)

Comment: Is that something specific to blender? Maybe ask in a blender-focused forum such as https://blender.stackexchange.com/ -- And since it is not really a question about Python code, but rather an issue about system configuration, maybe SuperUser could also be a good place to ask: https://superuser.com/ -- Only thing I can think, is that the situation seems bad, the Python installation seems all over the place. Not sure why you have MSYS/MinGW involved here... Maybe simply install a clean Windows Python from https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Yes as 35308 said, it seems like you have multiple Python interpreters on your system (which is OK), but it seems like you do not consistently use the same one. It seems like you run sometimes Blender's Python interpreter, sometimes MSYS' one, and then obviously get inconsistent results. -- You should only use Blender's Python, if necessary by using its full path in order to avoid surprises. -- Also you might want to read this: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to install pip by installing it using blender python like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\bin\python.exe -m ensurepip
```

and then upgrade I upgraded it

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\bin\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have had a similar problem, it seems to be a problem of mixing up multiple different Python interpreters. [Blender has an embedded Python interpreter](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_overview.html#:%7E:text=Python%20in%20Blender,Blender%27s%20internal%20tools%20as%20well.), this can be seen in your error message

`C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\bin\python.exe: No module named pip`, this is blender python not having pip, `C:\WINDOWS\system32>python3 -m ensurepip` is then ran but it's not the same python, here's the python version you installed.

Following [this](http://www.codeplastic.com/2019/03/12/how-to-install-python-modules-in-blender/) guide has worked for me, the main idea is to

```
cd C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python
```

As you already attempted you need to run the module ensure pip (but with python blender). So:

```
.\bin\python.exe - m ensurepip
```

You can now run

```
.\Scripts\pip3.exe install PySimpleGUI
```

or whatever module and it should be accessible from within blender.

for more information (although I'm not sure how still relevant it is) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules

Comment: I have tried your advice and some errors occurred. `Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code     exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`

Comment: Is there an actual folder at "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\Scripts"? if so, does it contain any pip exectuable ?