# Portable Python pip execution fails on "module pip not found"

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I wrote a simple Nodejs script that checks if Python is installed with the specific version and if not it will install a portable version via zip.

Executing Python works fine but when I try to install sth via pip with  :

`.\python.exe -m pip intstall xzy`

it says that pip is not installed.

When i check the Scripts and lib folder where python is installed i see the pip.exe

here is my script :

```
import { exec, spawn } from 'child_process';
import fs from 'fs';
import axios from 'axios';
import os from 'os';
import path from 'path';

const platform = os.platform();

async function getPythonPath(version: string): Promise<string> {
    const pythonFolder = path.join("public", "python", version)
    const pythonCmd = path.join(pythonFolder, 'python');

    if (fs.existsSync(pythonFolder)) {
        return platform === "win32" ? pythonCmd + ".exe" : pythonCmd;
    }

    let pythonUrl: string,
        pythonZipPath: string,
        unzipCmd: string,
        pipCmd: string;
    if (platform === 'win32') {
        pythonUrl = `https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${version}/python-${version}-embed-amd64.zip`;
        pythonZipPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), `python-${version}.zip`);
        unzipCmd = `7z x ${pythonZipPath} -o${pythonFolder}`;
        pipCmd = `${pythonCmd}.exe ${path.join(pythonFolder, 'get-pip.py')}`;
    } else if (platform === 'darwin') {
        pythonUrl = `https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${version}/python-${version}-macosx10.9.pkg`;
        pythonZipPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), `python-${version}.pkg`);
        unzipCmd = `sudo installer -pkg ${pythonZipPath} -target /`;
        pipCmd = `sudo ${pythonCmd} ${path.join(pythonFolder, 'get-pip.py')}`;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Unsupported platform');
    }

    try {
        console.log(`Downloading Python ${version}...`);
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: pythonUrl,
            responseType: 'stream',
        });

        const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(pythonZipPath);
        response.data.pipe(fileStream);

        await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            fileStream.on('finish', resolve);
            fileStream.on('error', reject);
        });

        await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`Unzipping Python ${version}...`);
            exec(unzipCmd, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });

        // Download get-pip.py
        console.log('Downloading get-pip.py...');
        const getPipUrl = 'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py';
        const getPipScriptPath = path.join(pythonFolder, 'get-pip.py');
        const getPipResponse = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: getPipUrl,
        });

        fs.writeFileSync(getPipScriptPath, getPipResponse.data);

        await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('Installing pip...');
            exec(pipCmd, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });

        return platform === "win32" ? pythonCmd + ".exe" : pythonCmd;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

export async function pyrun(scriptPath: string, pythonVersion: string, callback: (text: string) => void, onerror: (text: string) => void): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject) => {

        const pythonExecutable = await getPythonPath(pythonVersion);
        const command = `${pythonExecutable} ${scriptPath}`;

        exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }

            if (stdout && callback) {
                callback(stdout);
            }

            if (stderr && onerror) {
                onerror(stderr);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

this is my try to run it :

```
import path from "path";
import { pyrun } from "../basic-py-run";

async function main() {
    const version = '3.9.0';
    const installScript = path.join('public', 'python', version) + ' -m pip install cowsay';

    await pyrun(installScript, version, (text) => {
        console.log(text)
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });


}

main();
```

Comment: Did you try to simulate the steps that the script takes manually? Did you try to verify that the code does what you expect at each step? For example, did you try to check that the `await axios({method: 'get', url: getPipUrl});` part is reached and runs successfully? Did you try to check that, after that happens, there is a file called `get-pip.py` in the `pythonFolder`?  How about each other step? [What exactly do you mean by](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) "it says that pip is not installed."?

Comment: If `pip.exe` exists, why not do `pip.exe install xyz`?  Are you sure your `pip.exe` is the same version as your `python`?

Comment: We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: "when I try to install sth via pip with : `.\python.exe -m pip intstall xzy`" - do you mean when the script tries to use a command like that, or when you try to use it manually from the terminal, after using the script? Aside from that, just to make sure: you understand that `.\python.exe` means a program named `python.exe` **in the current working directory, not** an "installed" copy in a system-specific location, right?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you try to use python embed on win32:

> ```js
> if (platform === 'win32') {
>     pythonUrl = `https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${version}/python-${version}-embed-amd64.zip`;
> ```

After running `get_pip.py` with Python embed, you have to modify your `pythonXX._pth` file in the root folder.

Add `Lib\site-packages`, to get something like this:

```
pythonXX.zip
.
Lib\site-packages
# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site
```

You can get more info on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60829519/2226755

Answer (score 0):

there's a typo in your installation command. In your main function, you're trying to run a Python script using the -m flag, which is used to run Python modules. The correct way is to directly run the pip install cowsay command with the executable, (getPythonPath).  The -m flag is not needed when executing pip commands.. I've corrected your main function:

```
import path from "path";
import { pyrun } from "../basic-py-run";

async function main() {
    const version = '3.9.0';
    const installScript = `cowsay`;

    await pyrun(installScript, version, (text) => {
        console.log(text)
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}

main();
```

Answer (score -2):

If you find yourself needing to invoke the `python.exe` from its direct path rather than the system path, then you're going to need to do the same for `pip`.

You should try this:

```
.\python.exe -m .\pip.exe intstall xzy
```